# I'm struggling to understand the FIR Filter and its application

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, gnuradio, decimation

I'm new to GNU Radio, and I was watching this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu0NgIfXn4c&t=3712s&ab_channel=EuropeanGNURadioDays) However, I didn't quite understand the purpose of the FIR Filter. I know what decimation or downsampling is because I have the book "Digital Signal Processing" by John Proakis and Dimitris Manolakis. However, I didn't grasp how FIR Filters are explained in the book. The use of taps and why it has its relation with a lowpass filter is still not clear to me.

If there is a mathematical expression to understand it better, it would be appreciated. I am working on a project where I have to receive a signal from a cubesat and process the signal. In many cases, the FIR Filter is used:
[image]

Comment: The corresponding math expression is convolution. If you familiar with Fourier transforms you might remember that FT of a convolution is a product of FTs. This means that applying FIR shapes the spectrum of the signal by multiplying it with FT of the filter.

Comment: Are you familiar with moving-average filter? That is indeed a lowpass FIR filter.